# Classifier training long time due to the size data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn, tsne

I have a problem to train my classifier. I have 10 different kinds of music genres, each genre with 100 songs, after making an Mfccs I have a numpy array of **(1293, 20)** If all together with np.vstack I have an array of **(1293000, 20)** and another for the labels.

When I run `model.fit (features, labels)`, it takes a lot of time. I have also tried with:

```
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
X_embedded = TSNE (n_components = 2).fit_transform(features)
X_embedded.shape
```

I've tried to reduce the songs from 1000 to 100 but it's still taking a long time. Any idea how I can classify songs with arrays with so much data?

I put some code:

```
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
y, sr = librosa.load('EXAMPLE1')
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20).T
mfcc_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(mfcc)
mfcc_scaled.shape # (1293, 20)

y, sr = librosa.load('/Users/josetorronteras/AnacondaProjects/Neural-Networks/genres/pop/pop.00044.au')
mfcc2 = librosa.feature.mfcc(y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=20).T
mfcc_scaled2 = scaler.fit_transform(mfcc2)
mfcc_scaled2.shape # (1293, 20)

tmp_arr = []
tmp_arr.append(mfcc_scaled)
tmp_arr.append(mfcc_scaled2)
mafcc_list = np.vstack(tmp_arr)

mafcc_list.shape # (2586, 20)
a0 = np.zeros(len(mfcc_scaled))
a1 = np.ones(len(mfcc_scaled2))

labels = np.concatenate((a0, a1))
labels.shape # (2586,)
```

Comment: From your post I don't understand **which classifier** are you actually trying to learn...

Comment: @JanKukacka TSNE, is the classifier. I read in internet that it is prepared to big data

Comment: I think you misunderstood t-SNE: It is a method for dimensionality reduction, converting your high-dimensional space into a low-dimensional one which is easy to visualize. **It does not perform classification.** Moreover, it might be prepared for high-dimensional spaces, however, as it involves computation on all pairs of samples, it will most likely not scale well on datasets with many points.

Comment: @JanKukacka, You are absolutely right, I was wrong is a SGDClassifier.

Comment: I still think you are a bit confused. SGD stands for "Stochastic gradient descent", which is an optimization algorithm. The class "SGDClassifier" from sklearn package implements several classification algorigthms which use SGD for training, and depending on which `loss` parameter you choose, different classification algorithm will be used.